# Android SipManager close gives error "no data connection"

Tags: android, sip

Using the built-in Android SIP stack, I have a soft phone that successfully registers and makes calls. But when exiting the app I call the SipManager's close() method I see using "adb logcat" that it fails to unregister because it doesn't have a data connection. The phone I'm testing with is on WIFI and has uninterrupted access the whole time.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
manager.close( me.getUriString() );
```

SipRegistrationListener calls method onRegistrationFailed() with errorCode -10 (DATA_CONNECTION_LOST) and errorMessage "no data connection". From "adb logcat":

```
D/CallManager( 3197): unregisterPhone(SIP:2345678@12.34.56.78 Handler (com.android.internal.telephony.sip.SipPhone) {4355db80})
D/MyPhone(10130): MyService.MyMethod() Got "onRegistrationFailed" with errorCode "-10" and errorMessage "no data connection".
```

Answer (score -1):

Android WiFi error is going viral. Everyday number of Android users complain about this error. They try their best to contact Google for solutions but with no success.

- Reload WiFi Driver
- Use Different Options to Reload WiFi Driver
- Modify Network Configurations
- Clean Device Cache
- Try Wi-Fi Fixer App to Resolve the Problem

Source:-
Google
http://www.winphonedroid.com/fix-android-wifi-error/

Comment: Thank you. The fact that it's on WIFI doesn't seem to be important though, as if I disable WIFI and use 4G it gaves exactly the same error.